# Truncate/Round varchar columns in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, decimal, rounding, varchar

I have 2 columns Total and OccupiedBeds which are varchar datatype.

I need to calculate Occupancy = OccupiedBeds/Total and using below code:

```
CASE 
        WHEN isnull(cast([OccupiedBeds] AS INT), 0) = 0
            THEN 0
        ELSE cast([Total] AS float) / (cast([OccupiedBeds] AS float) / 1000)
        END AS Occupancy
```

o/p:

```
Total OccupiedBeds Occupancy
0          0    0.00000000000000
0          0    0.00000000000000
0          0    0.00000000000000
8         736   10.86956521739130
7         638   10.97178683385579
4         367   10.89918256130790
6         460   13.04347826086956
```

I need to truncate/Round the Occupancy so it can be shown as % on a chart.

I tried replacing float with decimal(19,2) but showing below results:

```
Total OccupiedBeds Occupancy
0            0      0
0            0      0
8            736    10.8695652173913
7            638    10.9717868338558
4            367    10.8991825613079
6            460    13.0434782608696
```

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

You can basically use the `ROUND` function, rather than changing the data type:

```sql
CASE 
    WHEN isnull(cast([OccupiedBeds] AS INT), 0) = 0
        THEN 0
    ELSE ROUND((cast([Total] AS float) / (cast([OccupiedBeds] AS float) / 1000)), 2)
    END AS Occupancy
```

UPD:

Your `Occupancy` formula looks a bit strange too, perhaps you need to calculate it as `OccupiedBeds / Total * 100`:

```sql
CASE 
    WHEN isnull(cast([Total] AS INT), 0) = 0
        THEN 0
    ELSE ROUND((cast([OccupiedBeds] AS float) / cast([Total] AS float) * 100), 2)
    END AS Occupancy
```